# Cannot override UserCreateSerializer of Djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I would like to add additional fields when user registering.

I created an app `account`.

Added it to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
]
```

In account I've created `serializers.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer

class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = (
            settings.LOGIN_FIELD,
            settings.USER_ID_FIELD,
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
        )
```

I've changed `SERIALIZERS` setting of `DJOSER`:

```
DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer',
    },
}
```

`urlpatterns` in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

When I send POST data to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/users/` new user successfully registered. But fields 'first_name', 'last_name' are empty!

I think DJOSER SERIALIZERS doesn't see `'user_create': 'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer'`.

My question - what I did wrong? How can I override `UserCreateSerializer` of Djoser?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the line:

```
DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    ...
```

If we use `'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True` we must override `'user_create_password_retype'`, not `'user_create'`!

So, in my case, `SERIALIZERS` section must be:

```
DJOSER = {
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create_password_retype': 'account.serializers.CustomUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer',
    },
}
```